# SQL return the most recent record of a specific type if a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully I don't make this complicated.
I wrote the following SQL that returns the users that their most recent transactions meet a condition 
(TRANS_TYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 21, 23) OR DEPOSIT_OPTION & 64 <> 64).

```
SELECT 
TERMINAL_ID,REGISTER_ID,[USER_ID],sub.CREATE_DATE,sub.TRANS_TYPE_ID,BUS_DATE_ID
FROM (
SELECT
T.TERMINAL_ID
,US.REGISTER_ID 
,U.[USER_ID] 
,T.CREATE_DATE
,T.TRANS_TYPE_ID
,T.BUS_DATE_ID
,T.TRANS_CONFIG_ID
,TT.TRANS_TYPE
, row_number() 
over (partition by U.[USER_ID] 
order by T.CREATE_DATE desc) rn
From [RCMDYNAMIC].[dbo].[Transaction] T
INNER JOIN [RCMDYNAMIC].[dbo].[UserSession] US ON T.USER_SESSION_ID = US.USER_SESSION_ID
INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[User] U ON U.[USER_ID] = US.[USER_ID]
INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[TransactionType] TT ON T.TRANS_TYPE_ID = TT.TRANS_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[Register] R ON US.REGISTER_ID = R.REGISTER_ID
) sub
LEFT JOIN
[RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[DepositConfig] DC
ON sub.TRANS_CONFIG_ID = DC.DEPOSIT_ID
WHERE sub.rn = 1 AND (TRANS_TYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 21, 23) OR DEPOSIT_OPTION & 64 <> 64)
```

I acquired the " most recent transaction" by using

`row_number() 
    over (partition by U.[USER_ID] 
    order by T.CREATE_DATE desc) rn`

However, what I really want is selecting the most recent transaction of TRANS_TYPE = 10 IF the most recent transaction met the previous condition.

The sub query in the previous code will return all transactions for all users and rank them in DESC order and the outer SELECT will display the users that meet the condition by checking their Rank 1 transaction.

What I want is having something like this

FOREACH user
IF the user rank 1 transaction meet the condition 
THEN 
FIND the user most recent transaction of TRANS_TYPE 10

it could be the transaction rank 1 or rank N

Example:

```
User_ID   TRANS_TYPE  DEPOSIT_OPTION Rank
   1           4           7          1
   1           10          7          2
   2           22          64         1
   2           23          4          2
   2           10          126        3
   2            4          7          4
   3           10          3          1
   4           6           64         1 -- doesn't meet the condition 
   4           10          7          2
```

form the previous results if the Rank 1 row satisfies the condition

```
WHERE sub.rn = 1 AND (TRANS_TYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 21, 23) OR DEPOSIT_OPTION & 64 <> 64)
```

I want the TRANS_TYPE= 10 to be displayed so I would expect the result to be:

```
 User_ID   TRANS_TYPE   Rank
   1           10        2
   2           10        3
   3           10        1
```

I am sorry if the question is not very clear I tried my best!

Comment: Added the sql-server tag since this is sql-server syntax

Comment: How about doing us a favor and provide some data and giving us some concrete 'what I'm expecting' values?

Comment: almost sounds like an `apply` is needed instead of a join.

Comment: I tried to add an example of what I'm expecting as you can see if the first condition in the Rank1 met then I want the first TRANS_TYPE 10 to be selected

Comment: Why user_Id 1 is in the output and User_Id 4 is not in the output? What is the difference?

Comment: Hello @KannanKandasamy I made that entry to show the condition that excludes the entries that don't meet the condition in USER_ID  = 4 , the TRANS_TYPE in (4,6,21,23) AND it's DEPOSIT_OPTION & 64 = 64 (bitwise operation &).

Comment: Why user ID 2 is in the output and user ID 4 is not? What is the difference?

Comment: @DeanSavović UserID 4 Rank 1 row has Trans_TYPE of 6 and the condition is (TRANS_TYPE NOT IN (4, 6, 21, 23) OR DEPOSIT_OPTION & 64 <> 64)

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists dbo.Deposits;

create table dbo.Deposits (
User_ID int
, Trans_Type int
, Deposit_Option int
, Rank int
);

insert into dbo.Deposits (User_ID, Trans_Type, Deposit_Option, Rank)
values (1, 4, 7, 1), (1, 10, 7, 2)
, (2, 22, 64, 1), (2, 23, 4, 2), (2, 10, 126, 3), (2, 4, 7, 4)
, (3, 10, 3, 1)
, (4, 6, 64, 1), (4, 10, 7, 2);

select
sub2.User_ID, sub2.Trans_Type, sub2.Rank
from dbo.Deposits sub
inner join dbo.Deposits sub2 on sub.User_ID = sub2.User_ID
        and sub2.Trans_Type = 10
where sub.Rank = 1 AND (sub.Trans_Type NOT IN (4, 6, 21, 23) OR sub.Deposit_Option & 64 <> 64)
```